# Is there a way to make a resharper rule to discourage ref & out parameters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, structural-search

It's my *opinion* that `ref` & `out` parameters hurt code readability. In most instances they can be replaced using generics & nullable types.

I'd like to have resharper warn when someone tries to define a function that has a ref or out parameter. However, all I've been able to find is a way to refactor methods declared to use out parameters. There doesn't seem to be any existing inspections or way to write a custom pattern targeting ref & out parameters.

Here's a common use of an out parameter:

```
int i;
if(!int.TryParse(str, out i))
{
    i = -1;
}
```

Compare that to this:

```
var i = str.TryParse<int>() ?? -1;
```

TryParse is just an extension method on string. I have a custom resharper rule that underlines any ValueType.TryParse() calls. *Note that now it's possible to parse a string as part of a linq expression.*

```
T? TryParse<T>(this string str) 
{
   //magic
}
```

Comment: Why would you EVER want this?

Comment: I believe a rationale is necessary here.

Comment: @ofstream, while I might consume methods such as `xx.TryParse`, I would very rarely elect to write such a method in my own code. A simple *discouragement* seems reasonable. "You have created a `ref` parameter. Should you return a proper type instead?"

Comment: @ofstream: I don't know if this is the scenario the OP has in mind, but, we occasionally have people who lack understanding and think they must use ref if a method modifies properties or fields of a class instance passed in as a parameter.

Comment: What would you want to encourage developers to use instead? A Tuple (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Transform_Out_Parameters.html)? Or something different?

Comment: @levelnis, presumably a well defined class. Maybe you guys haven't had the great fortune of working on codebases where developers have routinely tried to sneak in additional (and sometimes *several* additional) return values from a method. Or code that passes in (perhaps multiple) locals to other methods for (conditional) modification. It makes it more difficult to reason about the code when the feature is (ab-)used. So yeah, a note of caution to say "slow your roll, nephew" *before* it gets to code review could prove valuable for a given development team.

Comment: @ofstream just because it exists doesn't mean it should be used or is even useful. C# also has `goto`, you know.. There are scenarios where ref & out are necessary (in certain framework functions), but there's never an instance where you would need to use these in user-defined functions.

Comment: @levelnis the link you gave is what I mentioned in my post. I *know* that resharper has a refactoring to transform ref & out, but what I want is a code inspection to highlight it as an error.

Comment: @dan There are several cases where you should encourage the use of `ref` or `out` parameters. For example, if you have a type that can parse a string into an instance of the type, `TryParse` is a long-established, clear, expected way to handle the operation without throwing an exception and users should not be trying to find alternatives to it. Furthermore, the `bool Try*(args, out result)` format is the expected form of a method that may fail but an exception should be avoided for performance reasons. By trying to find a "better" way, you're just creating a library full of unexpected methods.

Comment: -1: The question may be valid but the presentation is overwhelmingly and unnecessarily argumentative.

Comment: @280Z28 I've made the question nicer ;)  However, I don't find the performance argument compelling--isn't it a micro-optimization? If I'm parsing strings, then most likely I've gotten those strings from an IO operation that dwarfs any perf advantage to using the out parameter version. Nor do I find tradition a compelling reason to use up developer time on reading & writing boilerplate code.

Comment: @dan - I would highly discourage you from using any TryXXX method that does not return a Boolean.  Your example returns -1.  This goes against the expected usage pattern of the TryXXX pattern in the framework.  I would instead create a new pattern and call it SafeParse, or ParseWithDefault, because that's what you're doing.. You're not Trying to parse.. You are parsing, and returning a default with failure... Try not to redefine existing framework or language patterns, as it causes confusion.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch that's a fair critique not to redefine framework patterns. fwiw, my example returns null, not -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my surprise, the following custom pattern actually works:

```
$type$ $X2$($pb$, ref $pt$ $i$, $pa$)
{
$stmts$;
}
```

Where

X2 is an identifier
i is an identifier
type is a type of object or derived
stmts is any number of statements
pt is any type object or derived
pa is any number of arguments
pb is any number of arguments

This matches `public int X(ref int y)` as well as `private int X2(string j, ref int i, DateTime k)`.

I have not found a way to match `void` methods.

This is with ReSharper 7.1.1 on Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Thanks. I've been very interested in custom patterns. They can do so much, and yet are still limited. I didn't know I could put parameters before and after a specific parameter, and didn't know that ref or out would work.

Comment: I was able to get your pattern to work on voids by making two copies, and in the second replacing `$type$` with `void`.  It's too bad the documentation on patterns is so sparse, I haven't been able to find anything much online other than trivial examples.